# SetTimeout is returing wrong value

Tags: javascript

```
function updateTime() {
  var currentDate = new Date()
  var day = currentDate.getDate()
  var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
  var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
  var d = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
  var hours = currentDate.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getHours() : currentDate.getHours();
  var minutes = currentDate.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getMinutes() : currentDate.getMinutes();
  var seconds = currentDate.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getSeconds() : currentDate.getSeconds();
  var t = hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds;
  var x = d + " " + t;
  return x;
}
console.log(updateTime());
var timerId = setTimeout(updateTime(), 1000);
alert(timerId);
```

Am trying to do a javascript timer. Here UpdateTime function is working properly. Its returing the exact result. But time is constantly being displayed. It should change according to the system time. Hence am using the setTimeout function. But its not returing the proper value. Can anyone help me out here please?

Comment: [`setTimeout` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) can help, `setTimeout` return a timeout id, not what you expect

Comment: `setTimeout(updateTime, 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the alert and () from setTimeout's callback function,

Your code should be

```
function updateTime() {
  var currentDate = new Date()
  var day = currentDate.getDate()
  var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
  var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
  var d = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
  var hours = currentDate.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getHours() : currentDate.getHours();
  var minutes = currentDate.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getMinutes() : currentDate.getMinutes();
  var seconds = currentDate.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getSeconds() : currentDate.getSeconds();
  var t = hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds;
  var x = d + " " + t;
  return x;
}

setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);
```

Comment: aButtons: [
                    { sExtends: "csv",
                      sFileName:  'GlData_' + updateTime() + '.csv',
                      sButtonText: "<i class='fa fa-file-text'></i>",
                      mColumns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
                    }, But i want to use timestamp with the file name as shown in the above code. Its working. But the problem is after 5 min also its showing the same time as a file name. When you refresh the page then only time will be changed in the file name. Please help me @ Jaromanda X @Swarnendu Paul

Comment: You are calling updateTime() function at the time of creating the json object, thats why  sFileName is remaining same even after 5min, and updates on page reload.
You should make sure that you create the json at the time when you need the updated file name.

Comment: What i have to use with sFileName, please guide? @ Swarnendu Paul

Comment: create your json as aButtons: [ { sExtends: "csv", sFileName: 'GlData_', sButtonText: "<i class='fa fa-file-text'></i>", mColumns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }.  without calling updateTime(). and while you are creating a new file call updateTime() to generate new file name
var new_file_name = obj.sFileName+"_"+updateTime()+".cvs";

Comment: Here am not creating any newfile. Am just exporting my HTML Table data into XLS, PDF, etc. How to handle here? Please help me @Swarnendu Paul

Comment: If you are exporting data on any button click then create the json on that button click just before calling export function.

Answer (score 0):

timer in javascript with current date

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>


    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer ,1000);
    function myTimer() {
        var d = new Date();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

what would you do ?

Comment: I have used this code. But Am not  displaying the timer in HTML page. Am using it a javascript object as a timestap for the filename.     
aButtons: [ { sExtends: "csv", sFileName: 'GlData_' + updateTime() + '.csv', sButtonText: "<i class='fa fa-file-text'></i>", mColumns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] },

Answer (score 0):

I just edit Your code hope it will help you

```
    function updateTime() {
  var currentDate = new Date()
  var day = currentDate.getDate()
  var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
  var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
  var d = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
  var hours = currentDate.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getHours() : currentDate.getHours();
  var minutes = currentDate.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getMinutes() : currentDate.getMinutes();
  var seconds = currentDate.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + currentDate.getSeconds() : currentDate.getSeconds();
  var t = hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds;
  var x = d + " " + t;
  alert(x);/*display time */
}

setTimeout(updateTime, 1000);/* just remove () braces from your code */
```